# content chnge via useState

Tags: reactjs

i'm just starting to learn react, where did i go wrong, can't undestand what am i doing wrong [this is my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mL6QP.png)

**my goal: to ensure that the picture changes as true / false**

**maybe I am not passing props correctly??**

it's my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import styles from './styles.module.scss'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import classNames from 'classnames'
import DjalKokildak from '../../../../assets/images/DjalKokildak.png'
import Turpachaty from '../../../../assets/images/Turpachaty.png'

const Fields = ({image}) => {
    const data = [
     {
            img: {
                true : DjalKokildak,
                false : Turpachaty
            }
        }
    ]
    console.log(data)
    const [image, setImage] = useState(true)
     
    return (
     <div className={styles.container}> 
        <div className={styles.wrapper}>
            <div className={styles.line} />
            <div className={styles.contentBlock}>
                <div className={styles.titleBlock}>
                    <h1 className={styles.title}>месторождения</h1>
                    <p className={styles.text}>“Джал-Кокильдак” и “Турпачаты”</p>
                    <Link to='/' className={styles.link}>подробнее</Link>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.actionBlock}>
                    <button onClick={() => setImage(false)} className={styles.button}>след</button>
                    <div className={styles.imgBlock}>
                        {data.map(item => item.img === img && (
                            <img src={item.img[setImage]}>{image}</img>

                        ))
                        }
                    </div>
                    <button onClick={() => setImage(true)} className={styles.button}>пред</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
     </div> 
    )
}

export default Fields
```

Comment: what does console.log(data) return ?

Comment: it's returns array
```[
    {
        "image": {
            "true": "/static/media/DjalKokildak.e2a04a64.png",
            "false": "/static/media/Turpachaty.38582bf6.png"
        }
    }
]```